# How to get classes src attributes with Playwright

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

When I put this code in Chrome console it has 48 classes

```
document.getElementsByClassName('J_ItemPic img');
```

```
HTMLCollection(48) [img#J_Itemlist_Pic_651487520082.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_621527472382.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_651916695401.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_630179610840.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_629449365972.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_634993482629.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_634320548805.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_631478235165.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_645754343179.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_632492103269.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_637026412260.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_602936795915.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_626875806633.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_629001628429.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_631463935294.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_637145338629.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_633082319414.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_649553800784.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_650696727621.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_633481506466.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_623839428208.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_644763521629.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_651749639117.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_618353248027.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_644857845009.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_633899021149.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_631732327485.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_628993216729.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_629487001599.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_629733480402.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_634755393944.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_616516599193.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_644716178292.J_ItemPic.img, 
img#J_Itemlist_Pic_629446501087.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_603686274087.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_634419684260.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_630295858342.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_631062820782.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_589015183052.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_634779139459.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_627821359162.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_610273912861.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_610784939062.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_648059057440.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_531997407471.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_581013461059.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_637977572817.J_ItemPic.img, img#J_Itemlist_Pic_629967677694.J_ItemPic.img, J_Itemlist_Pic_651487520082: img#J_Itemlist_Pic_651487520082.J_ItemPic.img, J_Itemlist_Pic_621527472382: img#J_Itemlist_Pic_621527472382.J_ItemPic.img, J_Itemlist_Pic_651916695401: img#J_Itemlist_Pic_651916695401.J_ItemPic.img, J_Itemlist_Pic_630179610840: img#J_Itemlist_Pic_630179610840.J_ItemPic.img, J_Itemlist_Pic_629449365972: img#J_Itemlist_Pic_629449365972.J_ItemPic.img, …]
```

And each classes has 'src' attribute and I want to get all 'src' attributes and make it to array.

And I thought this code will work but it only returns empty array.

```
let imgs = await page.$$eval('.J_ItemPic img[src]', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')));
console.log(imgs);
```

I already tried `page.getAttribute(selector, name[, options])` method but it seems that it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make it using Javascript Destructuring Assignment - ES6, try this one :

```js
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('J_ItemPic img');
const imageSources = [...images].map(image => image.src);
console.log(imageSources);
```

You can read more about Javascript Destructuring Assignment Array in [MDN Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does what you'd expect, the only thing that can cause an empty returned array is the fact: you need to wait until the src-s are loaded into the DOM when you open it with Playwright. You can make sure about this:

1. Using [`page.waitForSelector`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector) to make sure the element is loaded (I'd suppose it won't help, as it would have already thrown an error in `page.$$eval`)
2. **Check if the img src-s are [lazy-loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading) and scroll them into view (or other techniques to make them available in the DOM) before evaluation.**

You can even shorten it to `img.src` in the returned value (omitting `.getAttribute('src')`):

```js
let imgs = await page.$$eval('.J_ItemPic img[src]', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.src));
```

---

+
3. Check if your element is within an iframe, because in that case `page.$$eval` will have a different scope than [`frame.$$eval`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-frame#frame-eval-on-selector-all).